# Trying to create a welcome image code with Jimp (Latest version: 0.16.1) as well, using latest version of Discord.js (13.6.0). I'm trying for hours

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm facing a problem trying to develop a bot... I'm trying to to make a "welcome image" with Jimp (Coding with Javascript) for my bot. Everything works fine, except the jimp part [Using the **client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member =>** code. The code is showed below:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
  
  let channel = client.guilds.cache.get('932114971935014982')
  let mask = await jimp.read('mascara.png')
  let background = await jimp.read('download.jpg')

  await jimp.read(member.user.displayAvatarURL({format: 'jpg'})).then(async avatar => {
  avatar.resize(130, 130)
  mask.resize(130,130)
  avatar.mask(mask)

  background.composite(avatar, 10, 20).write('SenseiAvatar.jpg')
  await channel.send(``, { files: ["SenseiAvatar.jpg"]})

  console.log('Imagem de boas-vindas ao novo Sensei enviada com sucesso!')
  })
  .catch(err => {
  console.log('There was an error loading the image')
  })
})
```

If someone can help me, showing me which things are wrong in my code, I'll be so much praised by it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know `jimp` but I really recommend you `canvas`. It's very easy to make welcome images.

Example welcome image with `canvas`:

```
const Canvas = require("canvas");
const { MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js");

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
  const user = member.user

  canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(1024, 500);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const font = "sans-serif"
  const font_color = "#ffffff"
  const bg_color = "#000000"
  const title = `${user.username} has joined the server`
  const subtitle = "YOUR SUBTITLE HERE"

  ctx.fillStyle = bg_color;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.font = `42px ${font}`;
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillStyle = font_color;
  ctx.fillText(title, 512, 390, 950);

  ctx.font = `32px ${font}`;
  ctx.fillStyle = font_color;
  ctx.fillText(subtitle, 512, 440, 950);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(512, 179, 129, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(512, 179, 119, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.clip();

  const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(
    user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "jpg", size: 1024 })
  );
  ctx.drawImage(avatar, 393, 60, 238, 238);

  const channel = await member.guild.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID");

  attachment = new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), "card.png");
  await channel.send({
    content: `<@${user.id}>, welcome`,
    files: [attachment],
  });
});
```